# How to handle browser back navigation for unauthorized users

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-mobile

I have a jQuery Mobile site

- It has login page,profile page,edit profile page.
- User can login and access the other pages.
- I am maintaining a session using a cookie which holds the login status for 30 mins.User can logout  by clicking on logout button when user is in any other page than login.On logout the cookie is deleted and the user is redirected to login page.
- When user logout and hits back button the user is navigated to the previous page which is not authorized as the user has already
  logged out.

Is there a way that we can stop the user from navigation  to the back pages which are unauthorized?

Answer (score 2):

You should have server-side code on the top of every page to check if the user is logged in, and redirect if he's not. If the back button still works after logout, it means the browser is showing a cached version of the page (and probably the users can't navigate further from there).

Answer (score 0):

Try this simple script:

http://viralpatel.net/blogs/disable-back-button-browser-javascript/

it reloads the current page when you try to go back.

Comment: This is a bad solution. Breaks back for EVERYTHING.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everybody for your contribution.I found another way which was helpful to handle the back navigation to unauthorized page.I would like to share this with you all.Using setInterval function i was able to know the session availability every second.Below is my code with comments.

```
var userDetails = getUser( );//get the user details from cookie
if(userDetails != null) // if user session exhists
{
if(userDetails.remember == 0){
var IDLE_TIMEOUT = 30 * 60; // set 30 minutes inactive timeout 
var _idleSecondsCounter = 0; // counter to count seconds starts from 0

//extend the session timeout by extending the cookie expiry by 30 minutes if the user is active and set the counter to zero
document.onclick = function() {
        updateCookie();
    _idleSecondsCounter = 0;
};
document.onmousemove = function() {
    updateCookie();
    _idleSecondsCounter = 0;
};
document.onkeypress = function() {
    updateCookie();
    _idleSecondsCounter = 0;
};

//function to check the idle time and 
function CheckIdleTime() {
    _idleSecondsCounter++;
    var curPage = $('.ui-page-active').attr('id');

    if (_idleSecondsCounter >= IDLE_TIMEOUT && curPage != "login")
    {
            delcookie(); //once session timeout occurs delete the cookie
            alert("Session Timeout");
            $.mobile.changePage( "#login", { transition: "slideup", changeHash: true });
    }
}
window.setInterval(CheckIdleTime, 1000);//check idle time every second
}
}else// if user session does not exhists
{
    $.mobile.changePage( "#login", { transition: "slideup", changeHash: true });
}
```